# Is there a bug in Azure RTOS ThreadX's tx_event_flags_get function?

Tags: azure, real-time, threadx, azure-rtos

Calling the [tx_events_flags_get()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/rtos/threadx/chapter4#tx_event_flags_get) function with the "requested_flags" parameter equal to 0UL seems to result in infinite wait. Logically, it is pointless to wait for no flags to be raised; it should return immediately. Yet with this input the function never exits. Is this a bug in the function or am I missing something?

Here's the code I've written:

```
UINT ret;

TX_EVENT_FLAGS_GROUP evt_grp;
ret = tx_event_flags_create(&evt_grp, "evt_grp");

ret = tx_event_flags_set(&evt_grp, 1UL, TX_OR);

ULONG actual_flags;
ret = tx_event_flags_get(&evt_grp, 0UL, TX_OR, &actual_flags, TX_WAIT_FOREVER);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not missing anything. This is a bug. We will fix this in the next release, aiming for the end of April, 2022. In the future, it might be easier to post on github issues: https://github.com/azure-rtos/threadx/issues

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This was fixed in 6.1.11 here: https://github.com/azure-rtos/threadx/blob/master/common_smp/src/tx_event_flags_get.c